# Opening an ASCII file using R

Tags: r, raster

I am trying to open an ASCII file in R.This file is exported from a software of thermal camera. It has temperature values of crop. I am using following code:

```
library(raster)
r = raster("AA092800_1.asc") 
plot(r)
```

but  every time i am getting follwing error 
"not recognised as a supported file format
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file."

on examining the file, i found that there are commas instead of decimal points, I replaced all the commas with decimals but still the same problem  exists.

Please help me out.

The ASCII file is attached herewith.[original ascii file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ck19W85MFURnUtMXItaFJZRFU/view?usp=sharing)

same file comma replaced with decimal point text file. [comma replaced with decimal point text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ck19W85MFUYU5YN3p5MHlxRGc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 <- read.table("AA092800_1.asc", skip = 11, header = FALSE, sep = "\t")

head(df1, 2)
#      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16   V17   V18   V19   V20   V21   V22   V23   V24   V25   V26   V27   V28 ...
# 1 36,46 36,33 36,40 36,37 36,10 36,27 36,50 36,49 36,54 36,52 36,51 36,63 36,91 36,97 36,81 36,89 37,12 36,70 37,24 37,29 37,65 37,33 37,13 37,26 37,41 37,14 38,01 37,84 ...
# 2 36,68 36,38 36,39 36,41 36,32 36,42 36,50 36,53 36,39 36,49 36,53 36,54 36,62 36,84 37,06 37,16 37,48 37,60 37,35 37,32 37,39 37,12 37,06 37,33 37,46 37,99 37,87 38,15  ...
```

This time using `dec = ","` indicating `,` as decimal value

```
df1 <- read.table("AA092800_1.asc", skip = 11, header = FALSE, sep = "\t", dec = ",")

head(df1, 2)
#      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6   V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16   V17  V18   V19   V20   V21   V22   V23   V24   V25   V26   V27   V28  ...
# 1 36.46 36.33 36.40 36.37 36.10 36.27 36.5 36.49 36.54 36.52 36.51 36.63 36.91 36.97 36.81 36.89 37.12 36.7 37.24 37.29 37.65 37.33 37.13 37.26 37.41 37.14 38.01 37.84  ...
# 2 36.68 36.38 36.39 36.41 36.32 36.42 36.5 36.53 36.39 36.49 36.53 36.54 36.62 36.84 37.06 37.16 37.48 37.6 37.35 37.32 37.39 37.12 37.06 37.33 37.46 37.99 37.87 38.15  ...
```

For the other file, find the line number where Data begins and enter that number into `skip` argument.

Raster data needs data separated by `,`

```
df1 <- read.table("AA092800_1.asc", skip = 11, header = FALSE, sep = "\t")

library('raster')
df2 <- as.raster(as.matrix(df1))

head(df2)
# "36,46" "36,68" "36,82" "36,75" "36,67" "36,94"
class(df2)
# [1] "raster"
```

Comment: This command is very much appropriate for reading matrix. Can someone please suggest, to display this df1 as raster data.

Comment: Upvote by people below 15 reputation is not displayed publicly. I have already upvoted. In the question I have given       Plot (r)      which shows that the ascii is to be displayed as raster. Thanks for help.